# how to make datagrid content mutiline in Easyui

Tags: jquery-easyui

Like the picture1 display,I used datagrid to show a long text,and set the width of columns,but it can not diaplay total text,how could make it show like picture2. What should i do.
[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Answer (score 3):

set nowrap property to false in datagrid

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11007354)

Comment: setting nowrap:false in datagrid data-options="nowrap:false" is the solution for this.

Comment: "My" comment above is a rather auto-generated comment from review. Your post may solve OP's problem, but it's still rather a comment than an elaborated answer. But that's just my opinion and obviously not enough users agreed, so your answer is not deleted.

Comment: then this should be an accepted answer isn't it @DanielZhao?